# Python Timestamp + Datetime Conversion

Tags: python, datetime

I have a test record with a UNIX millisecond timestamp since epoch value of `1459952824358`

I am writing Python 2.x program using the fastavro library. That takes the `1459952824358` integer UNIX millisecond timestamp and converts it to a local datetime value of `2016-04-06T09:27:04.358000`. When I try to convert that back to a integer UNIX millisecond timestamp value I end up one hour off. I can replicate this conversion problem outside of the fastavro library with plain Python datetime:

```
import datetime
import time

raw = 1459952824358

local_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(raw / 1000.0)
local_dt.isoformat() # '2016-04-06T09:27:04.358000'

back = int((local_dt - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1.0e3)
back - raw # 3600000
```

I can convert to a UTC datetime and back successfully:

```
import datetime
import time

raw = 1459952824358

utc_dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(raw / 1000.0)
utc_dt.isoformat() # '2016-04-06T14:27:04.358000'

back = int((utc_dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1.0e3)
back - raw # 0
```

What is odd is that my system is set to CST or UTC-6, yet Python produces a local datetime that is *five* hours off of the UTC value rather than six.

While, my specific project requires Python 2 compatibility, I try the Python 3 `timestamp` function which correctly gives me back the original timestamp value without the hour drift, but the local datetime is still bizarrely 5 hours off of the UTC time, even when my system is set to CST or UTC-6.

```
import datetime
import time

raw = 1459952824358

local_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(raw / 1000.0)
local_dt.isoformat() # '2016-04-06T09:27:04.358000'

back = int(local_dt.timestamp() * 1000)
back - raw # 0
```

I try the same example in Java 9 on my same laptop, just to see what it produces:

```
import java.time.*

long raw = 1459952824358L;

Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(raw)
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneOffset.UTC)
// UPDATE: This line was my original attempt. It was wrong because it uses the current daylight savings setting, not the one of the given date.
ZonedDateTime zdtLocal = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset())
// This next line will choose the current geography, but choose the daylight savings setting based on the date, which is what I expected.
ZonedDateTime zdtLocal = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())

long deltaFromUtc = zdtUtc.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - raw
long deltaFromLocal = zdtLocal.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - raw
```

It returns back the exact original timestamp value regardless of utc/local.

UPDATE: Basically, Python 2.x can't properly convert a local datetime value to UTC without extra libraries. Python 3.x can, and Python 2.x has extra libraries to do this, but out of the box, it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Your measurement is off, not the datetimes: You're comparing two times from different timezones, so the result should be the difference between the timezones, and it is.

---

So this is why it's better to work in UTC:

In Python 2.7:

Using your raw:

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(raw/1000.0)
... print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(raw/1000.0)
... 
2016-04-06 14:27:04.358000
2016-04-06 07:27:04.358000
```

7 hrs different

Using a modified date outside Daylight Savings Time:

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1456952824)
... print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1456952824)
... 
2016-03-02 21:07:04
2016-03-02 13:07:04
```

8 hours different

This is happening because `raw` and `0` in the local time are in different timezones (Daylight Savings Time vs Standard):

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(raw/1000.0)
... print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(raw/1000.0)
... 
2016-04-06 14:27:04.358000
2016-04-06 07:27:04.358000

>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
... print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
...
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1969-12-31 16:00:00
```

If you stick to utc, no issues.

> but the local datetime is still bizarrely 5 hours off of the UTC time,
>   even when my system is set to CST or UTC-6.

Because on that `raw` date, your local time would be CDT (-5):

```
user@TS-E31:~$ date --date @1459952824
Wed Apr  6 07:27:04 PDT 2016
user@TS-E31:~$ date --date @0
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
```